# for_each call will not work with vector of pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, stl, foreach, huffman-code

I'm using a vector of pointers to free up a series of node objects in the heap. The vector has all the node object addresses and there is a function, delete_nodes, which is used with the for_each loop to delete all nodes in the vector. For some reason I get the following error in eclipse cdt with the for_each loop underlined in red:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'for_each(__gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Node**, std::vector<Node*, std::allocator<Node*> > >, __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<Node**, std::vector<Node*, std::allocator<Node*> > >, <unresolved overloaded function type>)'
```

The code is for Huffman coding, and the for_each loop is at the very end. The nodes_delete vector is created right before the while loop.

```
void Huff::delete_nodes(Node*n){//this is used to delete all the nodes in the binary tree at the end of Huff::compress()
    delete n;
}
vector<Code>* Huff::compress(){
    //-------GETTING WEIGHTS/FREQUENCIES------
    vector<Node *>* nodes = new vector<Node*>; // Vector of nodes for later use
    map<char, int>* freq = new map<char, int>; //  Map to find weight of nodes
    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < content.length(); i++)
        (*freq)[content[i]]++; 
    CopyTo copyto(nodes); //sets vector<Node*> to copy to 
    for_each(freq->begin(), freq->end(), copyto); // Copies 
    delete freq;
    vector<Node *>::iterator beg = nodes->begin();

    //-------SETTING UP TO BUILD TREE------
    if(nodes->size() % 2 == 1){ //makes sure there are an even number of nodes
        Node* fill = new Node;
        fill->set_node(0, '*', NULL, NULL);
        nodes->push_back(fill);
    }
    huff_sort(nodes); // sort nodes by weight
    vector<Node*> nodes_delete(*nodes); //this is used to delete all the nodes in the binary tree at the end
    //-------BUILDING TREE------
    while(nodes->size() != 1){ //Sorts nodes by weight and then removes two of them and replaces them with one
        int w= (**beg).weight + (**(beg+1)).weight;
        Node* p = new Node;
        p->set_node(w, '*', *nodes->begin(), *(nodes->begin()+1)); //making it the parent node of the two lowest nodes
        nodes->erase(nodes->begin(), nodes->begin()+2);
        unsigned int i = 0;
        while(w > (*nodes)[i]->weight && i <= nodes->size()){ //finds where to insert the parent node based on weight
            i++;
        }
        if(i > nodes->size()) //if it needs to be inserted at the end
            nodes->push_back(p);
        else
            nodes->insert(nodes->begin()+i, p);
    }
    //-------TRAVERSING TREE------
    Node* root = (*nodes)[0];
    delete nodes;
    vector<Code>* codes = new vector<Code>;
    traverse(root, codes , "");
    delete root;
    for_each(nodes_delete.begin(), nodes_delete.end(), delete_nodes);
    return codes;
}
```

Comment: Is there more than one (overloaded) definition for the `delete_nodes` function? In the code above I can see only one, but have you checked whether there is another one, perhaps in one of the header files?

Comment: @jogojapan There are no other delete_nodes as far as I know. Plus, if I change the name of delete_nodes to anything else, the error persists.

Comment: Btw I assumed the `delete_nodes` function is defined as a static member function. Is that actually correct? If not, Matteo Italia below is right (although I'd find the error message by the compiler rather misleading in that case).

Comment: @jogojapan No, I checked and it wasn't defined as a static member function. I changed it and it works now.

Comment: pointers to vectors and vectors of pointers... you are determined to leak memory aren't you? :)  Move semantics/RVO and smart pointers are your friend (if you even need pointers in you vector, which you probably do not).  You could also simply pass in a `vector<T>&` to be filled by the function.

Comment: There are way too many `new` and `delete` calls in the code. You might want to rethink what you need (a C++ book might be helpful)

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas Sorry, your comment is just a little confusing. What do you mean in the second sentence by 'need'. Also, I may be creating some design flaw, but whatever it is isn't covered in basic c++ books that I've read (as far as I know). SO could you be more specific on what kind of c++ book?

Comment: @MikeG: Did your books tell you to dynamically allocate standard containers? If so, consider getting different books. There are some times when you *need* to dynamically allocate objects, but for the most part you should be able to not write `new`, and surely you can do without `delete` (using smart containers for the few cases where you really need to dynamically allocate). What is your `Node` type? Do you *need* to store pointers to it in the `std::vector`? Or maybe just *values* suffice? The least pointers you use, the simpler the code.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas It was a pretty basic book so it didn't even mention using pointers with containers. The pointer to nodes was, as far as I know, unavoidable due to the way I was building the binary tree (which is what the program does). Thanks though, I'll look into what you said.

Comment: @MikeG: *pretty basic book so it didn't even mention using pointers with containers* --I am still waiting to find a book that instructs you to dynamically allocate containers. That is not an indication of *basic*.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It look like your `delete_nodes` is a non-static member function. If so, you cannot just use `delete_nodes` as an argument for `std::for_each`. `std::for_each` requires a functor. Your `delete_nodes` is not a functor.

Firstly, to obtain a pointer to a non-static member function, `&` operator and a qualified name are always required. A mere name of non-static member function (just `delete_nodes`) is not a valid expression in C++. You have to do `&Huff::delete_nodes`.

Secondly, again, a pointer to a member function (as opposed to a pointer to an "ordinary" function) is not a functor. In order to turn it into a functor you can use `std::mem_fun` function. That will give you a *binary* functor, since `std::mem_fun` will turn the implicit `this` parameter into an explicit one. In order to turn it into a unary functor required by `std::for_each` you have to bind the first argument to a specific object pointer value (`this` probably?).

The end result of the above steps will look as

```
bind1st(mem_fun(&Huff::delete_nodes), this)
```

This is a unary functor that calls `delete_nodes` for `this` object.

So, the `for_each` call in your example should look as follows

```
for_each(nodes_delete.begin(), nodes_delete.end(),
  bind1st(mem_fun(&Huff::delete_nodes), this));
```

However, it looks like in your implementation `delete_nodes` can be turned into a *static* member function. A static member function is an "ordinary" function, meaning that it is a functor and it can be used directly. I.e. if you make `delete_nodes` static your code should work as is.

Decide what path you wish to follow and make the necessary changes.

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to pass as a functor an unbounded member function. You have to bind it to the current object using e.g. [std::mem_fn](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/mem_fn) and [bind](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/bind).